# Manual Sort/Filter of Different Size List Items (List within a List)[Nested/Deep Structure Binding]

Tags: sapui5

I have a `List` with `CustomListItem`s and each `CustomListItem` has different amounts of Files stored within them. When I try to sort and filter the list items:

- The Sort functionality fails by:

Before & After Sort:

[image]
[image]

In the After Sort screenshot, the topmost row shouldn't have that much whitespace and the 2nd topmost row has the same amount of whitespace as the before photo (which it shouldn't). It's like the rows have phantom controls in them that haven't been moved by the sort. Furthermore, the original topmost row with the 10files now appears as a row with only 1 file (not pictured here) --which is how many white spaces were assigned to the original bottom row entry. Why is it doing this and how can I resolve it?

When I Inspect Element on the whitespace, there are invisible controls there..
[image: Inspect Element]

- The Filter functionality also is blowing my brains out. When I filter by a criteria that causes first entry (the one with the 10 files) to not appear, then I filter by a criteria that makes it appear again - this results:
  [image]

As seen here, all my 10 files that were dynamically instantiated are gone! Blasphemy! How can I resolve these glaring issues?

Background: Before dynamically instantiating the Icon+Link controls for each File, I had set 10 of them in the View. But the data would return empty rows that left excessive white space. Not only that, when I would Sort/Filter those rows, the same issue would happen here...I'm out of ideas of how to make Sort/Filter work with non-uniform-sized CustomListItems

My Code:

```js
that.getView().setModel(new JSONModel(oData.results), "noteAttach");
var aModelData = that.getView().getModel("noteAttach").oData;
var iModelDataLength = aModelData.length;
var aListItems = oList.getItems();
for (var j = 0; j < iModelDataLength; j++) { //sift through each DataEntry in the model
  for (var i = 1; i < 11; i++) { //in each DataEntry, find ppty Title1,Title2...up to Title10 & remove the ppties thatre empty. if not empty, create a downloadLink & icon for it
    if (aModelData[j]["DocType" + i].length === 0) delete aModelData[j]["DocType" + i] //remove the key-value pair entirely (both the key and the value)
    if (aModelData[j]["Title" + i].length === 0) delete aModelData[j]["Title" + i]
    else {
      var oEmptyVBox = aListItems[j].getContent()[0].getItems()[2]; // CustomListem.VBox.VBox
      oEmptyVBox.addItem(new HBox({
        items: [
          new Icon({
            src: {
              path: 'noteAttach>DocType' + i,
              formatter: formatter.customFileIcon
            }
          }).addStyleClass("sapUiTinyMarginEnd"), new Link({
            href: {
              parts: [{
                path: 'noteAttach>ObjectId'
              }, {
                path: 'noteAttach>Viewname'
              }, {
                path: 'noteAttach>Title' + i
              }],
              formatter: formatter.fileDownloadHref.bind(that) //'this' becomes controller instance instead of control instance
            },
            target: "_blank",
            text: {
              path: 'noteAttach>Title' + i
            }
          })
        ]
      }));
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<List id="listNotesAttachments" items="{noteAttach>/}" mode="None">
  <CustomListItem>
    <VBox class="sapUiSmallMargin">
      <HBox justifyContent="SpaceBetween" class="sapUiTinyMarginBottom sapUiTinyMarginEnd">
        <Title text="{noteAttach>CreatorName}" />
        <Text text="{parts:[{path:'noteAttach>NotesType'},{path:'noteAttach>CreatedOn'}], formatter:'.formatter.formattedDate'}" />
      </HBox>
      <Text class="sapUiTinyMarginBottom" text="{noteAttach>NotesData}" />
      <VBox/>
    </VBox>
  </CustomListItem>
</List>
```

Additionally, here is the Model properties you can refer to if need be:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That undesired behaviour is coming from the way you add the items to the second VBox. I have tried something similar with a second list inside each custom list item and after sorting by name, everything looks as you want to.

Before and after sort:

[image]

[image]

This is the view and controller details:

```js
var oData = new JSONModel({
  elements: [{
    text: "hello",
    text2: "bye",
    children: [{
      name: "a",
      id: "1"
    }, {
      name: "b",
      id: "2"
    }, {
      name: "c",
      id: "3"
    }, {
      name: "c",
      id: "4"
    }, {
      name: "c",
      id: "5"
    }, {
      name: "c",
      id: "6"
    }]
  }, {
    text: "kajsdfl",
    text2: "byasdfse",
    children: [{
      name: "ab",
      id: "12"
    }, {
      name: "ba",
      id: "23"
    }, {
      name: "ce",
      id: "34"
    }]
  }, {
    text: "he123321llo",
    text2: "by45556e",
    children: [{
      name: "a1234",
      id: "123"
    }]
  }]
});

this.getView().setModel(oData, "mockup");
```

```html
<List id="listNotesAttachments" items="{mockup>/elements}" mode="None">
  <CustomListItem>
    <VBox class="sapUiSmallMargin">
      <HBox justifyContent="SpaceBetween" class="sapUiTinyMarginBottom sapUiTinyMarginEnd">
        <Title text="{mockup>text}" />
        <Text text="{mockup>text2}" />
      </HBox>
      <Text class="sapUiTinyMarginBottom" text="{mockup>text}" />
      <List items="{path: 'mockup>children', templateShareable:false}">
        <CustomListItem>
          <core:Icon src="sap-icon://BusinessSuiteInAppSymbols/icon-traffic-lights" />
          <Link href="{mockup>id}" target="_blank" text="{mockup>id}" />
        </CustomListItem>
      </List>
    </VBox>
  </CustomListItem>
</List>
```

Therefore, I suggest you try a different approach by creating an entityset for the first list entry and a second one for the association of the second list. This way, as it did for me, all the things that are not working for you, will work as you expect them to.

Comment: i was going to ask what the `templateShareable` property meant, but then i was slapped with an error stating i needed exactly that. Thank you so much for the help, sir 8]